# Using CNTLM as a transparent proxy

Tags: proxy, transparentproxy

I'm trying to setup transparent proxying on both Ubuntu 15.04 and OSX 10.10. I'm on a corporate network so CNTLM is required to authenticate to gain access to the internet.

When I set the system wide proxy settings everything is fine. But because of a few technologies in our stack, I need transparent proxying.

Whenever I redirect all packets to CNTLM I get errors, why is another proxy like squid / tinyproxy required infront of CNTLM?

Comment: do you find any workarounds?

Comment: No, all my research pointed to the necessity of something to actually create the HTTPS connection before hitting CNTLM. I never got it to work